# Many GRASS add-ons do not work with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I use GRASS 6.4.3 on windows 7 64 bit.
GRASS has been installed with QGIS 2.6.1.

I have added r.stream.* adds-on by SVN.
For each add-on, messages of installation were : OK.

But when I try the command :
r.stream.order (or r.stream.basin or etc.)
I got an error message : 
*unable to fetch interface description for command 'r.stream.order'*.

When I try to use the .exe of the add-on, messages were : xxx.dll is missing;
xxx could be : libintl-8.dll or libconv-2.dll or libgrass_dbmiclient.6.4.3.dll ...

Have some ideas?

---

1) I install GRASS GIS 6.4.4.

2) I load r.stream.order via menu->parameter->list of extension->instal extensions from addons and the use of http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6

3) I write the command 'r.stream.order'.

4) But infortunately, same message : unable to fetch interface description for command 'r.stream.order'.

When I try from QGIS interface : the addon seams running BUT no file is created.

Answer (score 2):

GRASS GIS is not QGIS and it has its own user interface.

1) *unable to fetch interface description for command 'r.stream.order'*: if you want to use an add-on, you need to install GRASS GIS and not the version installed with QGIS which is designed to work with a QGIS interface (grass plugin and processing). The error  means that the plugin cannot build his GRASS interface

[image]

2) many add-ons need to be compiled to be installed (as r.stream.order) and Windows has no default C compiler (as Linux or Mac OS X) -> no compilation and error message *xxx.dll is missing*

3) you can find compiled add-ons for Windows in [Index of /grass64/addons/grass-6.4.3](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/grass-6.4.3/)

[image]