# Generating Hough transform (Hough line transformation) of binary image using QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, digital-image-processing, hough-transform

How do I generate a Hough transform (Hough line transformation) of a binary image in QGIS?

[image]

[image]

I tried in GRASS and I got Error: unable to fetch interface description for command

I found from the link: [Many GRASS add-ons do not work with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/many-grass-add-ons-do-not-work-with-qgis), "if you want to use an add-on, you need to install GRASS GIS and not the version installed with QGIS which is designed to work with a QGIS interface (grass plugin and processing). The error means that the plugin cannot build his GRASS interface".

I tried r.houghtransform on GRASS GIS but it yielded no results. The raster file can be accessed with the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YL6m41eAGEMHhBDr8hjyHa906FSKgbNQ?usp=sharing

I followed the following steps in GRASS GIS but no results was rendered:

Step 1: Import raster data> Simplified raster import with reprojection [r.import]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Step 2: In Console: r.houghtransform

[image]

Step 3: r.houghtransform User Interface

[image]

Step 4: Select Run

[image]

Comment: It seems Grass has a tool for it. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.houghtransform.html Did you try it?

Comment: Error in GRASS: unable to fetch interface description for command

Comment: Error in GRASS GIS for Windows: 'r.thoughtransform' is not recognized as an internal or
external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you tried to google the error message? There are several hits if you google with a similar problem (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293253/qgis-3-2-grass-processing-algorithms-not-working)

Comment: I found a solution:  if you want to use an add-on, you need to install GRASS GIS and not the version installed with QGIS which is designed to work with a QGIS interface (grass plugin and processing). The error means that the plugin cannot build his GRASS interface" from the link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/many-grass-add-ons-do-not-work-with-qgis I tried r.houghtransform on GRASS GIS but it yielded no results. The binary raster can be accessed on the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YL6m41eAGEMHhBDr8hjyHa906FSKgbNQ?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you set the https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region to the input raster map (`g.region raster=rastermap -p`)? And: did the command finish but you got an empty map (might be the issue with the computational region) or did an error message show up?

Comment: You are missing *before* "Step 2: In Console: r.houghtransform" to set the computational region to the map. Reason: the display and the computational region are distinct from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try with your dataset and obtained the Hough lines (note that I didn't attempt to optimize the Hough transform parameters). The computation took some 20min or so on my "average" laptop.

Result:

[image]

Procedure:

```
grass79 -c epsg:32618 ~/grassdata/epsg32618
Starting GRASS GIS...

# import GeoTIFF
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > r.import Binary\ Raster.tif  output=rastermap
Importing raster map <rastermap>...
 100%

# set computational region to raster map
# https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > g.region -p
projection: 1 (UTM)
zone:       18
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      378975.8392
south:      378905.4782
west:       353507.7774
east:       353583.0939
nsres:      0.01856001
ewres:      0.01856
rows:       3791
cols:       4058
cells:      15383878

# show imported map
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > d.mon wx0
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > d.rast rastermap
 100%

# install addon https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.houghtransform.html
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > g.extension r.houghtransform
...
Installation of <r.houghtransform> successfully finished

# show the GUI
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > r.houghtransform --ui

# however, we continue with command line for now
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > r.houghtransform input=rastermap output=hough 
# ... this takes a while to compute...

# show name of resulting vector map
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > g.list vector
hough

# display vector Hough lines
GRASS epsg32618/PERMANENT:~ > d.vect hough color=red size=2
```

See above for the resulting vector map (red lines).

Comment: I edited the question with steps followed based on your recommendations but could not render any results. Can you kindly advise.

Comment: You are missing *before* "Step 2: In Console: r.houghtransform" to set the computational region to the map. Reason: the display and the computational region are distinct from each other.

Comment: @markusN could you show how to set the computation region in the Grass GUI? I am trying to compute hough transformations right now, but having trouble. I've only ever used Q and Arc before so having quite a time figuring it out on my own.

Comment: Please check https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/wxGUI.html#map-display-window --> Various zoom options --> Set computational region extent from display/interactively