# Using r.houghtransform in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, hough-transform

I am trying to draw lines that run the length of rows in an orchard. I have a nice binary image that I produced from an optical image (see below). I need to delineate the crop rows with a simple vector line segment running the length of each one.

[image: crop rows]

I discovered that GRASS GIS has a function that will compute lines in the N-S direction you can see from this sort of data ([r.houghtransform](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.houghtransform.html)). I ran the function in the GRASS GUI with this .tif file as input and got no result.

I then found [Generating Hough transform (Hough line transformation) of binary image using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383946) which mirrors exactly my problem, and a solution (see [@markusN's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384753/115) showing his inputs for the terminal prompt).

However, when I run this exact same code offered in the solution, with only my working directory, CRS and .tif as substitutions, I got no result. The error it returns says this:

`GRASS 7.8.5 (Kent):~ > d.vect hough color=red size=2 WARNING: The bounding box of the map is outside the current region, nothing drawn`

Thus, I suspect this has something to do with the computational regions not lining up. When I run the code in the GUI, I get a vector layer popping up in my map layers box, but if I zoom to layer it takes me to a blank space with no coordinates.

Why is this happening?

There is a study site specified by the input raster:

[image]

Comment: Your input raster has the same CRS as the project?

Comment: Yes! I have tried making new projects entirely just to confirm if this was the problem.

Comment: And did you set the computational region **at the start** to the extent of your binary raster (as in MarkusN's example)?

Comment: I believe so? I based the project extent on only this one single raster file. There's absolutely nothing else involved with the project. Just in case - could you walk me through what your process would be?

Comment: If you run `d.vect` then it belongs to `d.mon wx0` while the `g.gui` is a separate thing. I'd suggest to either use the former or the latter but not combine both. And yes, `g.region` comes first. Then, in case of the `d.mon` approach, run `d.erase` to tell the monitor about the current region. Or simply use `g.gui` for all...